# Why did dial up modems have speakers?

Tags: status, sound

In the days of dial up, everyone was familiar with the cacophony that was emitted from the modem as it was dialing up (if you need a reminder, [listen here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWFpwi4u1CA)). I know that those sounds were all representations of what was happening in the modem while a connection was being negotiated. This infographic does a great job of explaining it:
[image]

([Big version](http://hackadaycom.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/dial-up-handshake-infographic.png))

My question is: **why bother installing a speaker in every single modem and playing the connection negotiation every time?** You could argue that it would help in diagnosing a problem, but then why leave the speaker connected and the volume turned up by default? Some modems had a volume knob, but others like this PCI modem didn't.
[image]

If it was just for diagnosing problems, surely a technician could have plugged in a speaker to a port on the modem and only listened to it when needed. As far as I know, all internet connection software like AOL showed a progress bar or animated status icon of some form to indicate that a connection was being established. Why add the speaker?

Comment: I rekon it was quite musical!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've mentioned that a technician could have plugged a speaker into the modem, but many problems with modems were of a non-technical nature:

- Phone number was engaged.
- Wrong number and a person was answering the phone. Best to know about it early rather than continually calling back.
- Phone number kept ringing indicating a problem at the other end.
- General network announcements such as number disconnected.

So there were plenty of end-user scenarios where the speaker came in handy. It was normally enabled by default but with the popular [Hayes AT command set](http://www.modemhelp.net/basicatcommand.shtml) modems it could be muted with an `ATL0` command.

Comment: I could always tell whether I'd connected at 14400, 28800, or 56K based on the sound.

Comment: Also: to listen for the call waiting tone when there's an incoming call.

Answer (score 2):

From experience: This really was useful.

In addition to the obvious things like busy signals -- or having a human or fax machine pick up, which happened! -- which @PeterJ mentioned, most of us came to recognize the sound of a successful connection as it was negotiated, so the speaker provided a kind of audible "progress bar" on the connection.  For that reason, most of us did leave the speaker turned on until the connection had been made -- though it muted itself automatically after that.

This was also useful when someone dialed *into* your modem line -- you could hear their confused "Hello?" and pick up the phone to answer them.

It may or may not have originated as a hold-over from the days of acoustic couplers -- but there was certainly enough value to justify a few cents for a minimal speaker.